# JMockit : How to write tests a unit test for a class which relies on a peristence layer?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

My requirement is to write unit tests for logic that revolves around a bean that makes calls to a persistence layer.  The calls are mostly StoredProcs, and the goal isn't to validate that the stored procs are correct, but rather that the logic in the class is accurate.

To this extent, I would like to somehow mock the calls to the persistence layer, but haven't found an easy way to do this this.  I suspect it is because it isn't really the ideal/recommended approach (persistence layer classes should theoretically be tested with integration tests).

In this particular instance, however, I am comfortable mocking the persistence layer.  Given the following code snippet:

```
public boolean isUserDataPresent(String username, PersistenceManager pm) throws IzoneBusinessException {
    // call the last date the data was refreshed
    LastOperation lastOp = getLastOperation(username, pm);
    return username != null && lastOp!= null && lastOperation.getActiveMergeDate() != null;
}
```

wherein `getLastOperation()` is a private method which access the DB via calls to the `PersistenceManager` and returns a private inner object `LastOperation`, how can I safely and effectively test this method?

```
private LastOperation getLastOperation(String username, PersistenceManager pm)  {

    LastOperation lastOperation = null;
        try (CallableStatement cstmt = pm.getConnection().prepareCall("{call GetLastOperation(?)}")) {
            cstmt.setString(1, username);
            if (cstmt.execute()) {
                ResultSet resultSet = cstmt.getResultSet();
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    lastOperation= new LastOperation(resultSet.getTimestamp(1));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    return lastOperation;
}
```

Comment: Stored procs in 2018?!? Last time I worked with them was in the 1990's... Anyway,   why can't you mock the `PersistenceManager`?

Comment: @Rogério Theoretically, I can mock the `PersistenceManager`, but that means also mocking the `CallableStatement` and the `ResultSet`, which I was hoping to avoid.  It just seemed rather convoluted to go to that extent, so I wanted to see if there was another/easier way to accomplish it.  I've edited the question to show a sample of what the `getLastOperation()` method looks like.

Comment: Sure, mocking all that would be awful. The problem here seems the lack of proper abstractions. If you have multiple calls to stored procs, there should be an easy to use helper class which hides the low-level JDBC code. Then, that could more easily be mocked. Personally, I would write a real test which checks the meaningful business operation, executing the stored procedure. Unless there is a separate test suite for those stored procs, I wouldn't mock them.